Issue with Duplicated Text When Reopening Notes in a Collaborative Setup with Yjs, Quill, and SQLite
I'm facing an issue with my collaborative text editor built using Yjs, y-websocket, and Quill. The editor allows users to work on notes collaboratively in real time. However, I'm encountering text duplication under the following conditions:
Issue Description

When does the duplication occur?


I open a note in the UI, enter some text, then leave the note (navigate away or click another part of the UI).
Upon reopening the same note by clicking the note icon in my UI, the previously entered text gets duplicated.
This issue also occurs when I refresh the page.


What works as expected?


Real-time collaboration between multiple users works well (no duplication occurs during simultaneous editing).
The issue only arises when a single user navigates away from a note and then reopens it.

Code Implementation
Here is the relevant implementation for the editor (TextEditor.jsx) and the Yjs WebSocket server (yjs-server.cjs).
TextEditor.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Quill from "quill";
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import "./TextEditor.css";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import * as Y from "yjs";
import { WebsocketProvider } from "y-websocket";
import { QuillBinding } from "y-quill";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import QuillCursors from "quill-cursors";

Quill.register("modules/cursors", QuillCursors);

const BACKEND_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL;
const YJS_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_YJS_URL || "ws://localhost:1234";

const SAVE_INTERVAL_MS = 2000;
const TOOLBAR_OPTIONS = [
  [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
  [{ font: [] }],
  [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
  ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
  [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
  [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }],
  [{ align: [] }],
  ["image", "blockquote", "code-block"],
  ["clean"],
];

export default function TextEditor() {
  const { id: documentId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const editorRef = useRef();
  const quillRef = useRef();
  const ydocRef = useRef();
  const ytextRef = useRef();
  const [noteName, setNoteName] = useState("Untitled Note");
  const [isCollaborative, setIsCollaborative] = useState(false);
  const [resourceId, setResourceId] = useState(null);

  const { user } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInitialContent = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/get_note?note_id=${documentId}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
          const content = data.content ? JSON.parse(data.content) : null;

          if (ytextRef.current) {
            ytextRef.current.delete(0, ytextRef.current.length); // Clear existing content
          }

          if (content && ytextRef.current) {
            ytextRef.current.applyDelta(content.ops); // Apply new content
          }

          setNoteName(data.name || "Untitled Note");
          setResourceId(data.resource_id);

          const isUUID = /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/.test(
            documentId
          );
          setIsCollaborative(isUUID);
        } else {
          if (data.error === "Unauthorized access") navigate("/");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching initial content:", error);
        navigate("/");
      }
    };

    fetchInitialContent();
  }, [documentId, BACKEND_URL, navigate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editorRef.current && !quillRef.current && resourceId) {
      editorRef.current.innerHTML = "";

      const ydoc = new Y.Doc();
      ydocRef.current = ydoc;

      const provider = new WebsocketProvider(YJS_URL, resourceId.toString(), ydoc);

      const ytext = ydoc.getText("quill");
      ytextRef.current = ytext;

      const quill = new Quill(editorRef.current, {
        theme: "snow",
        modules: {
          toolbar: TOOLBAR_OPTIONS,
          cursors: true,
          history: { userOnly: true },
        },
      });
      quill.disable();
      quillRef.current = quill;

      const binding = new QuillBinding(ytext, quill, provider.awareness);

      provider.on("status", (event) => {
        if (event.status === "connected") quill.enable();
        else quill.disable();
      });

      return () => {
        binding.destroy();
        provider.destroy();
        ydoc.destroy();
        quill.off();
        quillRef.current = null;
      };
    }
  }, [resourceId, YJS_URL]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={noteName}
        onChange={(e) => setNoteName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter note title"
      />
      <div ref={editorRef}></div>
    </div>
  );
}


yjs-server.cjs
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const { setupWSConnection } = require("y-websocket/utils");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

const port = process.env.PORT || 1234;

wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
  const ip = req.socket.remoteAddress;
  console.log(`New connection from ${ip}`);
  setupWSConnection(ws, req);
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Yjs WebSocket server running on port ${port}`);
});


Environment Details

Frontend Framework: React
Rich Text Editor: Quill
Collaboration Framework: Yjs
Backend: Flask (with SQLite as the database)
WebSocket Server: y-websocket

What I've Tried

I attempted to avoid applying the backend content when the Yjs document already has content, but this caused inconsistencies in real-time collaboration.
I suspect that the Yjs WebSocket server isn't persisting the document state correctly, but I would appreciate guidance on how to confirm this or configure it if necessary.

Expected Behavior

When I open a note, its content should be displayed without duplication.
Real-time collaboration should remain functional, with changes synchronized across all connected clients.

Thanks to anyone who can help me resolve this duplication issue.
